# Just need Date, Do not need Time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am loading data from an excel sheet to pandas. My excel have dates in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

When I read the data using pandas `df = pd.read_excel('sheet1')` and try to write the dataframe in SQL Server `df.to_sql()` the date values are written in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format in SQL Server.

However, I need date values in `MM/DD/YYYY` in my SQL Server. Also I do not need any time to show up in my table.

Any advise?

Comment: `date` values are stored as `date` values, they are binary, they don't have a format. If you want to display them then use `cast` or `format` when you select. You can choose between `date` and `datetime` types

Comment: @Charlieface thanks, will I be able to do cast or format in pandas. I want to Transform data before loading it to final destination(SQL Server)

Comment: So what are you asking? You need to insert the data as `date` or `datetime` so go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer I was looking for :

`df['Column'] = df['Column'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`

This will just give me dates and at my desired format. It will change the data type of the column to `'object'`.

---

If you want just the dates and DO NOT want time in `YYYY-MM-DD` use :

```
df['Column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column']).dt.date
```

This will just give you dates. But, the datatype will be `'object'`.

---

For datatype as `'datetime64'`

```
df['Column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Column']).dt.normalize()
```